# Trying to set up a discord bot. What did I do wrong here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to set up a discord bot with Discord.js. I have Node.js, Discord.js, and Visual Studio Code installed and have already set up an application and token for my bot. I can't seem to tell what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please help me? The error message I'm getting is here:

```
(node:12332) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('your-token-goes-here');

Thanks so much!
```

Comment: It looks pretty straightforward. There is some kind of issue with the code that handles receiving the token. You need to add some code for us to see in order to actually help.

Comment: Oops. Adding the code now!

Answer (score 4):

This error comes from [`Client#login`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=login). Discord.JS tried to establish a connection with Discord, but you provided an invalid token.

What you need to do is simple:

1. Go to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
2. Pick your application.
3. Go to the "Bot" section of your application, as in the following example:
   [image]
4. Simply copy your bot's token.
   [image]

---

Try to establish a connection between your Discord bot and Discord.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.login('Token');
```

Here's what a token should look like:

```
NjQxMzEzNjY3ODExNTA4MjM2.XcGj5Q.PTVPYBopHQUFvTf_VM792fyOggY
```